# Permutation on sitting arrangement

Tags: permutations

Question-In how many ways can eight people be seated around the table?

As the question state only table, I do not know whether it is a rectangular table or circular table as the answer can differ from the category of the table.
 As for the circular table, the answer is = $7!$
As for the rectangular table with 4 people on each side, the answer is = $4\times{7}!$ = $4\times\underbrace{7\times 6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}$ = $20160$.
Which one is correct teachers?

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to me: If you generally search the Web or look at such related problems, if they say: *Find the number of … seated around a table*, it generally refers to the fact that the people are seated around a circular table. See for example, this earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261325/seating-8-people-around-a-table).

But, generally teachers and problem books specify when students are to work on problems other than the above by explicitly stating the fact: *Find the number … seated around a **rectangular table** or around a **square table with two at the sides*** and the like. See for example, [here](http://mathhelpboards.com/discrete-mathematics-set-theory-logic-15/arrangement-eight-people-around-square-table-problem-grimaldis-book-1917.html).